# String buffer in java

Tags: java, string

```java
import java.lang.*;
class hello
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         StringBuffer s3 = new StringBuffer("R");
         String s1 = "Rahul";
         char ch = s1.charAt(0);
         System.out.println(s3.toString().equals(ch));
    }
}
```

Output should be TRUE but it is showing false. Please help.

Comment: @Juvanis: It compiles as per `String.equals(Object param)` and autoboxing of `char` to `Character`. param is not limited to `String`.

Comment: @Steph just noticed that, sorry. =)

Comment: Also, prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 4):

Most ovverridings of `equals` don't return true if the types aren't the same.

String's `equals` implementation is like this :

```
1012    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
1013        if (this == anObject) {
1014            return true;
1015        }
1016        if (anObject instanceof String) {
               ...
1030        }
1031        return false;
1032    }
```

Here, you're comparing a `String` and a `Character` (due to autoboxing, as an Object is needed).

What you can do is ensure you're comparing a string to a string :

```
    System.out.println(s3.toString().equals(""+ch));
```

or simply compare the characters, as you know `ch` is a character :

```
    System.out.println(s3.charAt(0)==ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to StringBuffer, it is because you compare th **String** "R" to the **char** 'R'

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the string `"R"` to the character `'R'` which according to Java isn't equal, because the types do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking equality between a `String` (s2.toString()) and a `Character` (ch) . So, it is returning false . For equality check you should first typecase that `char` to `String` .
You can use the following code:

```
System.out.println(s3.toString().equals(String.valueOf(ch)));
```